# Works on localhost but fails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memcached, delayed-job

I am using a delayed_jobs to run a task in the background.

I am starting a task using ajax, the worker gets some uuid and writes to cache the status of the task and the result.

then I use another ajax to poll every second and see if I got a result.

It works well on my localhost, but when I upload to heroku it does not.

I checked the logs, and I can see that the worker can read the cache it has writen, but when the main thread tries to access it its empty.

I am using thin server, memcachier and dalli.

This is the code used to write to the cache:

```
def self.get_meta_info(link_url,job_uuid)
    begin
      #..........
      result =  {
          title: "stuff here..."

      }
      #..........

      Rails.cache.write({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'result'},result.to_json)
      Rails.cache.write({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'status'},'success')

#the next to lines return the data in the logs
      Rails.logger.info("get_meta_info written to hash at #{job_uuid}")
      Rails.logger.info("get_meta_info result for #{job_uuid} was: #{Rails.cache.read({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'result'})}")

    rescue Exception => ex
      Rails.cache.write({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'result'},ex)
      Rails.cache.write({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'status'},'error')
    end
  end
```

This is the server side code I use for polling: (it is called by ajax every second)

```
  def get_meta_info_result
    job_uuid = params[:job_uuid]
    status = Rails.cache.read({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'status'})
    #the next to lines return nothing in the logs
    Rails.logger.info("nlp_provider_controller.get_meta_info_result for uuid  #{job_uuid} read status #{status}")
    Rails.logger.info("nlp_provider_controller.get_meta_info_result for uuid  #{job_uuid} read result #{Rails.cache.read({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'result'})}")
    respond_to do |format|
      if status=='success'
        format.json {render json: Rails.cache.read({job_uuid: job_uuid,type: 'result'})}
      elsif status=='error'
        format.json{render :nothing => true, status: :no_content }
      else
        format.json{render :nothing => true, status: :partial_content }
      end
    end
```

I have no idea how to solve that.

Tank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two days to solve this. Stupid mistake.

There are two configs, development.rb and production.rb. Not that I did not know that, but usually I config in a separate initializer.

I had the Redis configured in the delvelopment and not in the production one.

Added:

```
redis_url = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0/MyApp"
MyApp::Application.config.cache_store = :redis_store, redis_url
```

(based on: http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/06/connecting-node-js-to-redis-to-go-on-heroku/)

and it works.